# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver when reading data from database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, web.xml

I'm trying to create a web application which retreive data from a postgresql database, and these are the configuration files :

## web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name></display-name>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

## application-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/ schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value ="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="toor"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://172.16.83.128:5432/emaeval" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.models" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hiberante.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="tansactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

but when I run my application I get these errors :

```
AVERTISSEMENT: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3f7cb1d0 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

And :

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

How can I solve this problem ??

Comment: Looks like the jar containing `org.postgresql.Driver` is missing in your classpath.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. If you have a (totally) different problem: post a new question. Don't modify or edit your question to ask an additional but unrelated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misspelled the hibernate.dialect property in your xml, thats why your second error is complaining that you have not set it.

```
           <prop key="hiberante.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
```

should be

```
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem but after fixing it, I got another problem, please check the modification I made to my post

Comment: your new error seems unrelated to the original question which was regarding sql drivers etc. Perhaps a new question should be posted now as it looks like a web framework issue etc.